# Why NSMutableString inherits from NSString but not the other way around?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, oop

`NSMutableString` inherits from `NSString`, but

1. Inheritance works as a "is a" relationship.  So a Cat "is an" Animal.  But an `NSMutableString` "is not" an `NSString`.  (because `NSString` cannot mutate (cannot change))
2. Usually, what a subclass an do, then the base class should be able to do.  Such as a fish can swim, and some animal can swim.  But an `NSMutableString` can change, and `NSString` cannot change at all - no `NSString` whatsoever can change.

So why does `NSMutableString` inherits from `NSString`?  Also, `NSMutableArray` inherits from `NSArray`.  Shouldn't `NSString` inherits from `NSMutableArray instead`, but with a "do not change flag" set to YES instead?   What is the principle behind this?

**Update:** some answer will say: `NSMutableString` can do all things that `NSString` can, therefore `NSMutableString` inherits from `NSString`.  But can this principle be used?  A Stone can stay still.  A Cat can stay still, and can move.  A Cat can do all things that a Stone can, but we can't make Cat inherit from Stone, right?

If I have two game object classes: one is elastic object and one is non-elastic, I think it makes sense to implement the elastic one as the base class, and the non-elastic inherits from it with the flag that says the outer bound cannot change.

Comment: #1: a Cat is an animal, but not all Animals are Cats, and for #2, subclasses don't just refine or redefine existing behaviors of base classes, but most usefully, extend the base classes offering additional functionality.

Comment: Of course anybody can vote the way (s)he prefers. But I disagree with whoever downvoted the question. The question is clear and asked appropriately. The fact that the OP has not yet well understood inheritance does not grant a downvote (by definition every OP does not understand something, else (s)he would have no reason to ask anything).

Comment: The base class should be more broad and general. An animal is more broad and general, just like a mutable string is more broad and general. A non-mutable string is more "particular". So that's why looking at it this way, it makes sense that the base class should be the mutable one

Comment: A cat and a stone have no relation. a cat is not a stone, a cat does not extend a stone. and a stone is not a cat, it does not extend the cat. just because some classes are mutable they are not in a relation.

Comment: A cat can die and become a corpse or a fossil.  It would be strange to implement a Fossil class and let the Cat inherit from it, right?  If a game has fossil cat, we can in fact implement FossilCat and inherit Cat, right?

Comment: actually are you just trolling around? you could also say, that everything is made of elementary Quarks, gluons, electrons and the famous highs-bosom. does this knowledge leads you to an assumption, that these are the only objects in programming that should be existing? a dead cat's fossil may lie on a planet, it's sun goes to super nova, so the cat become pulverized and blown out to the universe, where it atoms may become part of new stars or other interstellar objects. is this an important fact to the knowledge, that a cat is a mammal is a animal?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic. It looks like the OP wants to get into a discussion of what he feels is a correct inheritance graph for mutable / immutable objects. This isn't the place for that kind of discussion.

Comment: @vikingosegundo No I am saying that most of the cases, I see the specific class inherit from the more general class, and your point of view seems to be "the more capable class should inherit from the less capable class.  Is the principle one way or the other, or can both design principle work?

Comment: Everything to answer you questions has been said. additionally you are hinted for Liskov Substitution Principle, duck typing and obj-c protocols. I see no need for further discussion.

Comment: First, is Liskov Substitution Principle a must?  Second, you are saying, we should define a Square class, and extend it to make it a Rectangle class, but I do see it the other way

Comment: Really? I'd write a Square class with a width property, and a Rectangle class with a width and height property. But this is all navel gazing.

Comment: I'd Write a shape class and inherit rectangle and square from it. Or maybe a shape protocol, rectangle and square must conform to.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Those are also good solutions. I think the point we are all trying to get across is that inheritance isn't some airy concept, but needs to have some relation to the problem domain that it is being applied to. Smarter people than I have spent a lot of time thinking about these things.

Comment: @Abizern I just wanted to point out, that inheritance isn't the only tool in OOP's toolbox. Or as a smarter man than me said: “If I revisited that decision today, I might even go so far as to remove single inheritance as well. Inheritance just isn’t all that important. Encapsulation is OOP’s lasting contribution.” — Brad Cox was asked, why Objective-C doesn’t have multiple inheritance.(Masterminds of Programming: Conversations with the Creators of Major Programming Languages, p. 259)

Answer (score 4):

> Inheritance works as a "is a" relationship. So a Cat "is an" Animal. But an NSMutableString "is not" an NSString

Wrong. NSMutableString **is** an NSString because it can do *whatever NSString can.*

> Usually, what a subclass an do, then the base class should be able to do

Also wrong. It's the other way around. It's rather "What a base class can do, it must also be doable by the subclass".

> Shouldn't NSString inherits from NSMutableArray instead?

I don't even see the relation between the two (as long as `wchar_t` is not a valid Objective-C object).

All-in all: the reason is that NSMutableString is able to do more things than NSString, and can do anything NSString can, hence the direction of inheritance.

Comment: You said NSMutableString can do whatever NSString can.  NSString can keep a string intact and never be changed no matter what.  Can NSMutableString do that?

Comment: @JeremyL read it as "responds to all the messages NSString responds to". Please stop being ignorant. (By the way, technically speaking, it can - `NSCFString`, which backs `NSMutableString`, *inherits from* `NSMutableString`, yet when instantiated from `NSString`, it throws an exception saying "Error: mutating message sent to immutable instance" - from that one can deduce that it *responds to* mutating messages (since there is no "Unrecognized selector" error), it just implements its elsely based on other conditions...)

Comment: @JeremyL, what is wrong with you? H2CO3 is trying to teach you the essentials of object orientated programming (oop), something that is the base of all class based oop. there is no need to react as you just did.

Comment: read the update in the original question.  I don't think you can say a class can do everything another class can and so the first class should inherit from the second.

Comment: @JeremyL see, I don't call ignorance when somebody doesn't know or doesn't understand something (because that's alright). The ignorance from you was that 1. You thought I wanted to offend by saying what was wrong and you also thought that the rules of inheritance are subjective (which they aren't). 2. You distorted my words - I'm sure you *knew* what I meant by "NSMutableString can do whatever NSString can", yet you continued to hassle about the wording.

Comment: But I don't think a subclass should do everything a base class can.  For example, a base class can be Bird, and we subclass Bird and have Sparrow and Ostrich, but we have to override the `fly` method of Ostrich because it can't fly.  So you see, the base class in this case is the "more capable" and the subclass is less capable.

Comment: @JeremyL what you describe is [duck-typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), not inheritance based sub-classing. In objective-c you can us protocols to achieve something similar. but you are asking for subclassing. and there the rule is: the subclass extends or re-defines the parent class' abilities.

Comment: @JeremyL again, it was probably a bad idea of mine to use the wording 'a subclass can do anything the base class can do'. It's not about the actual behavior. It's about the ability. A subclass has all the methods and instance variables as a base class.

Comment: So much for the summer of love :) @JeremyL I feel your understanding of inheritance is flawed, but if you want a discussion about what **you feel** the inheritance graph of NSMutableString/NSString is then there are other SE sites that are better suited for it.

Comment: must inheritance be "extending the abilities"?  I tend to think of it as from general to specific

Comment: @vikingosegundo are you saying subclassing Bird to define the Ostrich class is duck-typing?  And subclassing Bird to define the Sparrow class is not duck-typing?

Comment: no, saying, that everything that flies is a bird, is duck typing.

Comment: @H2CO3 you said " I'm sure you knew what I meant by "NSMutableString can do whatever NSString can", yet you continued to hassle about the wording." In fact, I don't.  I thought you mean it at a higher level of capability.  It seems that you mean "whatever methods it has, the other one has it too"

Comment: @JeremyL Yes, absolutely. And instance variables. And properties. Superclasses' members are, by definition, strict subsets of the members of their subclasses/

Answer (score 1):

The mutable versions add extra functionality to the immutable versions, which is why they inherit from the other.

But another reason you are missing is that the classes which have mutable/immutable versions are actually members of a [class cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html) which is hiding a lot of the implementation. So what you are thinking of as a simple class inheritance is much more than that.

The inheritance also allows a convenient method of applying the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: +1 for naming LSP. I just came back to add it to my answer, but found the link here.

Comment: Unfortunately I think the fact that a mutable type inherits an immutable one violates LSP. I.e. an NSMutableString has different behaviour to that of NSString since it can be modified by external code. A desirable property of NSString is the fact that it's immutable.

Answer (score 1):

A subclass<->class relationship is often referred to be a "is-a" relationship. But actually I think that Java's `extends` describes it better: A subclass extends the functionality of it's base class.

An NSString object knows everything to save string along with encoding.
An NSMutableString object knows all this but additionally knows how to alter that stored string, so it makes perfect sense to say "NSMutableString extends NSString"

from one comment:

> The base class should be more broad and general. An animal is more broad and general, just like a mutable string is more broad and general. A non-mutable string is more "particular". So that's why looking at it this way, it makes sense that the base case should be the mutable one

NSString IS more general, as it leaves you the oppertunity to create another subclass of it, that could add the altering functionality, without using the NSMutableString's implementation, why ever you would want that to do. If the functionality would be placed in NSString itself, you would be adding it just a second time and your objects would carry code, that is duplicated and this would lead to code bloat. There are also many situations, where your strings won't ever change, i.e. labels on buttons. It would be wast of recourses if the would be instanciated as mutable objects along with all the code for mutation.

> If I have two game object classes: one is elastic object and one is non-elastic, I think it makes sense to implement the elastic one as the base class, and the non-elastic inherits from it with the flag that says the outer bound cannot change.

No, that would be a weak design, as the non-elastic objects would carry all code with them, that is used for performing the elastic behavior.

Comment: but I don't think we design the class by thinking how much code is present.  The hierarchy itself is more important.  And the subclass simply have references back to the base class for the methods anyways, so not much is wasted.

Comment: as I just wrote under H2CO3 answer: you aren't talking about class subclass inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the inheritance means the enlargement and diversity of its original class, functionalities especially. A mammal is usually a land  living animal, yet dolphin may live in the sea. You may say that dolphin inherits from mammal and enlarged its functions in living in the sea.

Comment: but it is strange if my class can handle string but it is absolute not changeable, and now, I "extend" it, and now it becomes changeable.

Comment: Why would that be strange? `NSMutableString` can do everything `NSString` can. Additionally, it extends the class to be mutable.

Comment: That's exactly what inheritance is for. Modern human inherited from their ancestors, and can do far more than them (Say programming). That is the nature of inheritance, and maybe, evolution.

Answer (score 0):

Saying that inheritance works as a "is a" relationship is true but totally misleading. "is a" in english implies the full meaning of "to be". In the case of inheritance "is a" only implies subtype relationship (and it's good practice to code the classes so that the stronger Liskov substitution principle requirements are met).

A better english term (still not perfect, but better) would be "X does everything that Y does". Even better, in the typical OO terminology, it means "X has all the members that Y has".

A `NSMutable*` indeed is a subtype of an `NS*` and not the other way around as any (intrinsically non mutating) messages and properties of an `NS*` also apply to `NSMutable*` while any mutating messages or mutable properties of the latter would not apply to the former.

*Usually, what a subclass an do, then the base class should be able to do.* Is incorrect. It's in fact the other way around. What a base class can do, the derived class should be able to do too.

As for strings and arrays, in Objective-C arrays and strings have very different sets of methods. Just check the classes documentations. They are therefore completely separated in the inheritance hierarchy (except for the common `NSObject`, of course).

Regarding your example of stones and cats, of the **only** characteristic of a stone is that it stands still and the **only** characteristics of a cat is that it stand still or it can move, for suitable definitions of these properties it makes perfect sense to have a cat inherit from a stone.

Comment: so if we do use Liskov substitution principle, then we in fact will define a Square class and then extend it to create a subclass of Rectangle?

Comment: What class hierarchy directly implies is just subtyping (I'll edit my answer to clarify this). But it is good practice to actually only use it when the strongest requirements of Liskov are obeyed. As for whether rectangles and squares are related by subtyping and if the stronger requirements of Liskov are valid, depends on what semantics you attach to a rectangle and to a square (including, for example, if they are mutable). It may well be that they are not related at all.